# JQuery to add divs to list of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Hey I have a list of images that I need to wrap with divs so that every three images is in a new div. The first div has to start at the beginning and continue for the next three images before closing and opening the next div. The final HTML should look like this:

```
<div>
    <img />
    <img />
    <img />
</div>
<div>
    <img />
    <img />
    <img />
</div>
<div>
    <img />
    <img />
    <img />
</div>
```

I know that this should have to do something with the nth child selector but so far I've only been able to select single elements rather then being able to select three at a time.

Comment: you have given na final, but what's the initial?

Answer (score 2):

well,

```
$('img:nth-child(3n)').each(function(){
    $(this).prevAll('img').andSelf().wrapAll('<div/>');
});
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/R3Q6v/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
var imgListLength = $imageList.length, // assuming $imageList is your jQuery object
    tmpArray = $imageList.toArray(),
    newHtml = '';

for (var i = 0; i < imgListLength; i = i + 3) {
  newHtml += '<div>';
  newHtml += tmpArray[i] + tmpArray[i + 1] + tmpArray[i + 2];
  newHtml += '</div>';
}

$('body').append(newHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those images are in a container with the ID `container`, you could do this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/c2nQH/

```
var imgs = $('#container > img');

imgs.each(function(i) {
          // If we're on a multiple of 3...
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
              // ...take a slice of it and the next two, and wrap them.
        imgs.slice(i, i + 3).wrapAll('<div></div>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey guys I used patrick dw example and it worked out. Thanks!

Comment: @msegreto: Glad it worked out. If this was the solution you ended up using, please remember to click the large checkmark to the left of this answer.  Thanks. :o)